# error occurred during initialization of vm error opening zip file :error in opening JAR file <zip file is empty> c:\..\java\jre7\lib\rt.jar

Tags: windows-8, java

I have installed java and set the new environment variable on control panel under the name of

PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin

but when i run the command java -version on my command prompt it displays..[image]

I have windows 8-64bit running on my pc.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set the Environment Path to exactly the following:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
```

Locate the *rt.jar* file in *C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib* and make sure the size of *rt.jar* is not 0KB.

Try updating Java to the newest version.